# how to write my own regular expression in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

in asp.net i have to validate a text box control if it end with ".aspx" otherwise display error message
Please guide me to how to create a custom regular expression for this condition.

Comment: why not just .aspx if it is missing, why bother user with error messages? And if it's a link, why enter it manually - maybe it can be selected from a list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have to use Regular Expressions, but If you really want to, try:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(TextBox1.Text, ".*?\.aspx$"); 

                string[] var_matches = matches.Cast<Match>()
                                         .Select(match => match.Value)
                                         .ToArray();

if (var_matches.Length > 0)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

EDIT

If you want to use **asp:RegularExpressionValidator**, then try:

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"  ValidationExpression=".*?\.aspx$" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error!"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: .NET doesn't have a method `matches` exposed by `string`.

Comment: Your answer is still incorrect - take a look at usage of `Regex.Matches` (this isn't it; you're specifying the regex as the input).

Comment: That was a typo, i fixed it.

Comment: i want to do the validation using the regularExpression validator not by coding

Answer (score 1):

If you're dead-set on using RegEx, you could try something like the following:

```
private bool ValidateFilename(string input)
{ 
    RegEx r = new RegEx(@".*?\.aspx$");
    return r.IsMatch(input);
}
```

RegEx is not necessarily the best choice in this situation, however.

Comment: Not sure what the deal is with the plague of downvotes on answers to this question - is answering the original question correctly insufficient now?

Answer (score -1):

You can just take the last 5 chars and check them, you don't need a regex for that....

(check length before doing that...)

this is the regex:

> `".*?\.aspx$"`

Comment: i want to do the validation using the regularExpression validator tool not by coding